A Taylor Series for the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean
I let $f(x)=\operatorname{AGM}(1,1+x)$ on Wolfram Alpha and used various small values of $x$ to estimate $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$, and $f'''(0)$. I came up with $1/2$, $1/8$ and $5/27$, leading to $f(x)$ being approximately $1+ x/2 + x^2/16 + 5x^3/162$, but with lots of uncertainty. Can someone provide the actual Taylor series?

Hi! Your idea is astonishing. Do you expect to get results with less effort, since AGM converges pretty fast me think.

actually i had 1+x/2-x^2/16+5/162x^3 but I forgot and put +x^2/16.

I am sorry but your Taylor series is not correct.
It should  be
$$f(x)=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{x^3}{32}-\frac{21 x^4}{1024}+
\frac{31x^5}{2048}-\frac{195x^6}{16384}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ Limited to $O\left(x^4\right)$ as your, it is not good but better than the one you posted. Increasing the order even make the situation quite awful.
If we write the general form of the series, it is
$$f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,a_n\,x^n$$ where all $a_n$'s are positive with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim \frac 1n$.
If you want something much better, I would suggest to use the corresponding $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$.
For example
$$\large P_2=\frac {1+\frac{29 x}{24}+\frac{61x^2}{192} } {1+\frac{17 x}{24}+\frac{5x^2}{192} }$$
$$\large P_3=\frac {1+\frac{477 x}{280}+\frac{479 x^2}{560}+\frac{2139 x^3}{17920}}{1+\frac{337 x}{280}+\frac{177 x^2}{560}+\frac{19 x^3}{3584} }$$ are more than decent.
Compared to the Taylor series, their errors are $\sim\frac{x^5}{700}$ and $\sim\frac{x^7}{11600}$.
Edit
I forgot to mention that the above works decently for small values of $x$.
If you are concerned by large $x$, it is better to go back to the integral definition
$$f(x)=\frac \pi 2 \,\frac{x+1}{K\left(1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)}$$ Let $\color{red}{x+1=t}$ and use
$${K\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {c_n}{t^{2n}}$$ where, with $\color{red}{u=\log(4t)}$  the first coefficients are
$$\large\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & c_n \\
 0 & v \\
 1 & \frac{v-1}{4} \\
 2 & \frac{3(6 v-7)}{128}  \\
 3 & \frac{5 (30 v-37)}{1536} \\
 4 & \frac{35 (420 v-533)}{196608} \\
 5 & \frac{63 (1260 v-1627)}{1310720}   \\
 6 & \frac{77 (13860 v-18107)}{20971520} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
This works quite well even for small $x$.
For $x=1000$, using the above terms, the approximate result is $189.411$ while the exact value is $189.555$.

Thanks, can you provide a reference for the power series?

@RichardPeterson. I made them for you.

Thanks. I 'd like a reference.

@RichardPeterson. Do you want the reference for Taylor series ? As I said, these have been made for you (in particular the last one)
